# Nullreference exception unrelated to website code

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-10

Hi we have recently accidently had an aborted installation of windows 10.

Our web apps and websites were working fine and before the abort.

But now we have wierd errors seemingly unrelated to the website code.

When running the website from visual studio it is working fine.
But when accessing it from the browser either locally or from the outside we get the following error (no error code):

System.NullReferenceException
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlHead.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +201
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +46
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +79
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +159
   System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +38
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +79
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +8920

Any idea for a solution or what is causing the problem?

Comment: delete the cache of asp.net, try to check if the page go together with the correct code... and check again your code inside

Comment: Hi thanks, still the same problem :(

Comment: re-install asp.net